HELP - installing Chinese light fixture with wire colors that don't match!
I have an LED light fixture (from China) with only 2 wires, white and yellow. My existing wires coming from the old fixture are white and black. Should I connect white to white and the yellow to black?

follow the installation instructions

in which country are you located?

Lights usually do not care.  The wire used as hot should be the one that goes to the centre post/not the threads for your safety only.  Unless that light has UL/CSA/ETL(electrical safety testing labs) legal label, then it is not legal to use, and your insurance can denied any claims.

No instructions included. I'm in the US. I just looked over the fixture and don't see any labels, which makes me think I better find a new fixture!

The label is usually easy to find/see.  Chinese stuff might use the CE label, but that is not recognized in NA/US.
